# Can I do encoding before my model layers in Convolutional Network?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I'm interested in adding a special type of encoding to my images before they're fed into my subclassed tensorflow convolutional network. In the documentation, I have seen, "one-hot" or any encoding takes place within the layers module of tensorflow and then passed onto the Conv and other layers.

But, the encoding, I am interested into applying, it's present in a different library. So, If I encode my data with that library, my question is, how can I feed that encoded data to my tensorflow Conv layers?

**Currently my model looks like this-**

```
class AmmarNet(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(AmmarNet, self).__init__()
    # self.shape = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3)) # don't comment out this line as it might result in error
    self.encoding = CategoryEncoding(num_tokens=4, output_mode="one_hot"),
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
```

Comment: You could try encoding your data with the library you're interested in, and then passing the encoded data to the Conv layers in your tensorflow model.

Comment: I know that! But, I'm confused how to achieve it. Since Tensorflow does encoding using the layers module within the Neural Network. I'm struggling to understand whether if I preprocess the datasest i.e. encode it ex. one_hot using sklearn whether Tensorflow with pickup that encoded dataset and feed into the model or not? 

Since I ain't aware any evaluation metircs thorugh which I could find whether encoding before the model actually resulted being fed encoded data in the Tensorflow model, that's why, I need help to figure it out! Will really grateful, if someone could help :)

Comment: if the encoding have to take place "before u feed that as input to the model", and not in the middle of the forward pass, just do something like `input_encoded = your_transformation(original_input)` and then `model.fit(input_encoded, ....)`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new Layer via subclassing:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers


class CustomEncoding(layers.Layer):
    """A custom encoding class to apply other library"""

    def call(self, inputs):
        # apply the library on the inputs and return the result
        return some_library_function(inputs)
```

And then use this custom encoding class in your model:

```py
class AmmarNet(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super(AmmarNet, self).__init__()
    # self.shape = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3)) # don't comment out this line as it might result in error
    self.encoding = CustomEncoding(),
    self.conv1 = Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu')
```

More Info:

- [custom_layers_and_models](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/custom_layers_and_models)
- [CategoryEncoding](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/CategoryEncoding)